# Showing error explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display ajax data on datatable with pagenation and sorting. On doning I faced the following error
**explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, Closure given**

```
$empRecords = DB::table('permissions')
                                    ->select('id', 'name', 'updated_at')
                                    ->get();

           $empRecords->where(function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                    return $query->orWhere('permissions.name', 'ILIKE', '%' . $searchValue . '%');
                });
            $empRecords->whereIn('permissions.status', [1]);
            
              
            $empRecords->offset($row)->limit($rowperpage);
            $empRecords = $empRecords->get();
```

Comment: Where is your explode function ?

Comment: Error is showing in helper file

Comment: `$empRecords = DB::table('permissions')
                           ->select('id', 'name', 'updated_at');
 $empRecords->where(function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                    return $query->orWhere('permissions.name', 'ILIKE', '%' . $searchValue . '%');
                });
            $empRecords->whereIn('permissions.status', [1]);     
            $empRecords->offset($row)->limit($rowperpage);
            $empRecords = $empRecords->get();`

Comment: @JEJ Is this supposed to be an answer? Don't post answers as comments and provide an explanation.

Comment: Just for clarification: You were retreiving the collection with your first ->get() and then you did filtering the collection width `where` . The `Collection::where` function does not accept a closure. That's where the error happened. The filtering should be done in the DB-query as @JEJ showed.